# XCode 5 hangs loading a project

Tags: xcode

I'm working on an iPad app and I need to try a few things, for which I usually have a small sample app that I use. While my primary app project opens just fine, the sample app doesn't. Xcode (Version 5.0) just sits there, the wait cursor spinning. The other odd thing is that when trying to make a new project, I get the same behavior.

What's going on here? Various other threads on Stack and other forums suggest removing various files, in ~/Local/... and in the .xcodeproject directory. However this doesn't seem to help. Any ideas as to what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

I restarted my macbook and XCode behaves now. There goes my 200 day uptime...